# Ajax request with 'withCredentials: true' not sending all cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, asp.net-core

I have an Ajax request which looks like this:

```
ajax: {
    url: settings.apiBaseUrl + 'some/path',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    data: function (d) {
        return JSON.stringify(d);
    }
}
```

I also have various cookies that I want to send to the API endpoint with this request. One of these is a .NET Core Identity cookies named ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application". I also have two other cookies that I want to be sent to the API with the following settings:

Cookie 1:

- Secure
- 30 minute expiry
- SameSite: Lax

Cookie 2:

- Secure
- HttpOnly
- SameSite: Lax

I have all the CORS stuff sorted and the request gets through to the API alright but for some reason only the .NET Core Identity cookie is being sent, not my two custom cookies. How does `withCredentials` decide what cookies to send and how can I get my custom cookies to be sent as expected?

Comment: Ran into this just yesterday as well. As it happens, when sending a CORS request that uses a preflight request (like this one would), you need to make sure you're handing the `HttpOptions` method. Furthermore, I had to allow the HttpOptions method itself use anonymous auth. Basically just made a method like `[AllowAnonymous] [HttpOptions] public IActionResult Path() => Ok();`.

Comment: `HttpOnly` explicitly doesn't allow the cookie to be seen by JavaScript, so that one is never going to be sent.

Comment: @ChrisPratt is it really not going to be sent, or it is not going to be accessible thru javascript, but indeed being sent in the ajax request?

Comment: JavaScript has no access to any cookies set as HttpOnly. All withCredentials does is forward cookies it has, so it can't forward what it doesn't have.